# Writing multiple type of data into a list for it to be accessed by multiple threads

Tags: json, multithreading, spring-boot, crud

I send JSON's to my app via Postman in a list with a type of mapping(CRUD) to send it to my database.
I want my controller to put all this data, from multiple senders, in a list that will send the information to my DB. The problem is that i don't know how to store in the same list the Json and the Mapping, so when my threads do their work to know if that json must be inserted, updated, deleted and so on.

Do you guys have any ideea ?

PS: It is a spring-boot app that need to be able to send 12000 objects ( made from that jsons ) to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason for putting all data in one list and sharing it later, each HTTP request receives own thread.

On decent server you can handle couple thousands of requests/sec which perform simple CRUD operations.

Comment: Well i don't need a couple thousands, i need at least 12.000 per sec. The possibility of them being 12.000 of only POST methods exists, and i also would like to be able to raise this number if needed.

Comment: In such case you will might need to look into having multiple instances running, or microservices where each service will be for specific operation so you can scale each separately.